# technical understanding of flutter http request, serverside PrintWriter and clientside 200 code

Tags: java, google-app-engine, flutter

My flutter app sends a http request to my google-app-engine backend. In this request, a user's vote on a simple either-or-question is send and then stored in a mysql database. When that is done, the user sees another question and again votes. So, question, voting, question, voting, question, voting and so on.

Now, the user is not supposed to see the same question twice. Therefor, my mysql query that gets another question has a condition saying "download a question that user hasnt voted for yet". This works perfectly in like 99% of the cases. But in rare cases it happens that the user sees the same question again and again in a row for like 4 or 5 times, which tells me that my app might download the "next" question (which, in this case is the same question again) before the vote was stored in my database.

To debug this, I am trying to understand the technical stuff going on in background. Specifically, I need to know when the 200 statuscode fires after my app has send a users vote in a request. This is my serverside part when a voting is send:

else if (operation.equals("voteFav")){

```
        out.println("vote received");


        // get userID and favID
        Integer userID = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("userID"));
        String creatorID = request.getParameter("creatorID");
        Integer favID = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("favID"));
        String voter = request.getParameter("voterName");
        String winpic = request.getParameter("winpic");

        try{

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl);
            PreparedStatement ps;
            ResultSet rs;
            String query;

            // prepare Statement
            if(winpic.equals("1")) query = "INSERT INTO faved (favID, userID, voting) VALUES (?,?,1)";
            else if(winpic.equals("2")) query = "INSERT INTO faved (favID, userID, voting) VALUES (?,?,2)";
            else query = "INSERT INTO faved (favID, userID, voting) VALUES (?,?,-1)";
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);          

            ps.setInt(1, favID);
            ps.setInt(2, userID);

            // send vote to database
            ps.execute();               
            ps.close();



            // close connection     
            out.flush();
            conn.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            out.print("Fehler voting: " + e);
            out.flush();
        }


    }
```

My question is: When does clientside statusCode 200 fire? Does it fire immediately when I use the PrintWriter to write back "vote received" in the first line? Or does it only fire when I close the connection?

Hope it gets clear :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the 200 statusCode is sent from the backend in the moment you execute the ps. In the moment that you write in the database.

Since this issue occurs only sometimes, my opinion about your issue is that you may encounter some kind of lag while inserting the data into your database.

Comment: Thank you, Andrei, appreciate your help. You say "normally", may I ask how sure you are? I tried to google when exactly a server sends back the 200, but I only found general information like "200 occurs when request was successful", but that doesnt tell me whether my out.println("...") already results in a 200 or if my server waits - as you say - till the ps is executed.

It must have something to do with any kind of lag, indeed. I might have to find a way where server sends back a specific string only when the insert was successful and then on clientside wait for that specific string.

Comment: You can do it from your code. After the insert, you can do another query to see if the insert was made (if the data is inside the database and usable) and if it is true, display a message.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, problem solved. It was one weird line of code that I have no idea how it made it into my code. The query that asks for a new question does not only say "please return a new question that user with ID = 123 hasnt answered yet", it also has an additional filter, like "only questions matching topics food, fashion or sport".

Now, this filter is build dynamically in a for-loop in my preparedStatement:

```
// fill dynamically generated statement
                ps.setInt(1, userID);
                ps.setInt(2, userID);
                ps.setInt(3, userID);
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryIDs.length; i++){
                    ps.setInt(i+4, Integer.valueOf(categoryIDs[i]));
                    //ps.setInt(i+3, Integer.valueOf(categoryIDs[i])); this line is completely BS
                }
```

Position 3 in my statement is filled with userID that takes care of condition "which user123 hasnt answered yet". Now, see the commented line within the for loop? This line replaced my condition "which user123 hasnt answered yet" by "which user1 hasnt answered yet" in case topic 1 was chosen. So, my query was totally messed up.

So, anyway, problem solved :)